# How to deploy website to production with minimal impact to users

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment

I'm trying to find the best server architecture solution to deploy monthly updates to an Asp.net external public facing website.  What I'm looking for are ways to release a new version of a website with minimal impact to users.  Besides deploying the standard way (ie. stop IIS, copy new website over existing website, start IIS), what are some "better" solutions for deployment out there?   It would be nice if they kept their session and didn't have to see a "Website under maintenance" message during the update.

***My server configuration***

We have 2 IIS web servers (2003) and are trying to figure out the best way to utilize them for deployments.  My first thought was to update the non-active web server with the latest release.  Then to gracefully point the web traffic to that server with minimal impact to users (best case, the user doesn't lose his session).  How would you go about "repointing" the web traffic from server 1 to server 2?  Changing firewall NAT?  Changing DNS records?  Some other way??  We need to be able to test the live site immediately after we release the new changes (duh).

BTW, we are using nant and cruise control to automate the builds, and a custom web service to deploy the build to production.  So it's all automated with the click of a button.

Could a better solution be achieved using a 3rd server?  If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we do is

We have a load balancer from netscaler,

take one webserver out of loadbalancer , do all deployments, do a iisreset and the put back in load balancer.

Do the same thing for server2 .

Finally invalidate loadbalancer cache.

Comment: Just curious to know - Do you ensure that no users  have their sessions active on the webserver before you take it out of loadbalancer - and if so how? Or is it that you just use out of memory sessions like Database to ensure that users do not lose existing sessions?

Comment: @inSane , load balancer takes care of it, it depends how you set it sticky sessions or non stick sessoins. when the new request comes in the user is redirected to new webserver and as long as the url is correct it again uses the same session what he was using

Comment: I know this is a late comment, but thanks for the detailed explanation.  I'm guessing even though you upgrade 1 server and put it back in the load balancer, it doesn't mess everything up now that both servers have a different code base because of the load balancer cache?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a couple of things here:

- First, consider using a load balancing solution. Windows 2003 server ships with windows load balancing (WLBS), though its not the greatest product. It is, though, free. With that, you can point all traffic to one server, update it, and then do the opposite.
- Secondly, you may want to consider looking at how you're working with sessions. HTTP is stateless, which means that as long as you can reconstruct a user's session on any page hit, you should be fine. One ideal step towards this is using ASP.NET Forms Authentication - the cookie written by it isn't tied to an ASP.NET session. Of course, this approach leads to greater risk - there is a chance users will get an error screen if they hit something JUST AS you're copying files. And then there will be a delay while the app pool refreshes.

Overall, your better option is load balancing. Even with it, though, consider trying the second option as well - having sessions that can regenerate works well if users fail to be sticky to one of the servers in the pool.

Comment: Thanks john.  This confirms the load balancer is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add this for brevity. At my previous work, we achieved seamless deployments by using the following setup:

[image: ASP.NET webserver seamless deployment]

A load balancer would point to the production ASP.NET webservers (two in your case, but we had three), and the webservers would have their session setup to pull from a third server dedicated to hosting OutOfProc ASP.NET session.

To deploy a site, we'd pull one of the servers out of the load balancer, update the files, fire it back up, and place it back into the load balancer pool. Repeat for the rest of the webservers.

Because each webserver got the session data from the one central server, taking one webserver out, did not log out the users on that server.

If we had code changes that were incompatible with the existing session data, we'd wait till a scheduled maintenance window to deploy. Otherwise, users with that session data would get errors till they logged out.

Additionally, since this setup relies on the webserver being up, if you wanted to increase reliability, you could change the OutOfProc to SQL based session servers. You would need several servers that replicated the same session database and point the webservers to them. More complicated, but would reduce site downtime.